# What is the scope of python argparse

Tags: python, scope, argparse

This is probably a silly question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Consider this simple scenario:

```
# file a.py
from b import foo
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a')
args = parser.parse_args()

# file b.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-b')
args = parser.parse_args()

foo = 1
```

[prompt]# python a.py --help

> usage: a.py [-h] [-b B]
>
> optional arguments:   -h, --help  show this help message and exit   -b
>   B

What I don't understand is how come a.py accepts argument 'b' instead of 'a'
On a different note, how do I import only a variable and not the entire file? shouldn't 'from b import foo' deal with it?

**Edit:**
I have posted another question relating the same issue since I still don't know how to solve my issue ([is there a way to clear python argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864949/is-there-a-way-to-clear-python-argparse))

Comment: Anything that you don't want run when you import b, needs to go into a `if __name__` block.  While you may want to define a parser in b, you probably don't want to run parse_args.  In this case the b parse_args encountered a `-h`, and issued a `sys.exit`.  Input that didn't produced an error would be parsed by both parsers.  But if you want to use arguments defined by b's parser, consider importing it, and passing it as a parent to a's parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from b import foo` is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
import b
foo = b.foo
del b
```

Although it does "only import `foo`", it still runs all the statements at top-level of `b.py` (which is necessary for `foo` to be useful anyway), including the call to `parse.parse_args()`. This call will print the help text and completely ignore the `argparse` calls in `a.py` simply because those haven't occurred yet.

If you want your modules to be able to add arguments, you need to separate the creation of `ArgumentParser` from the call to `parse_args`. For example, you could have a separate `args` module:

```
# file args.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--common')
...
```

It would be used from both `a.py` and `b.py`:

```
# file a.py
from b import foo
import args
args.parser.add_argument('-a')

# only actually parse args if we are invoked as main script; mere `import a`
# shouldn't run the parser
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ...

# file b.py
import args
args.parser.add_argument('-b')

foo = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the fast and insightful answer. Suppose I have to do stuff in b.py with the arguments and b.py isn't the main file, is there some way to work around it?

Comment: @Ofir In that case I'd define a function in `b.py` that accepts the arguments and processes them, and call that function from the main file.

Comment: I'm still unsure how to resolve this issue as my b.py file relies on some of those arguments but you did answer my original question. 10x

Comment: @Ofir The part of `b.py` that relies on those arguments should be in a function (or functions called by that functions, etc.) invoked from the main module.

Answer (score 1):

You should only parse command line arguments if you are in the `__main__` namespace. To prevent `b.py` from parsing arguments, change it to the following:

```
# file b.py

foo = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-b')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

You should do similarly for `a.py`.

Comment: That won't work if both `a` and `b` need to independently add arguments to the argument parser. Note that in OP's code `a.py` adds `-a` and `b.py` adds `-b`, and the OP would like the resulting script to accept both.

Comment: That wasn't part of your question but you can still do that. In that case, you should only create the `ArgumentParser` object when you are in `__main__` but still add the args in the global scope of each file.