# is there a way to clear python argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

Consider the following script:

```
import argparse
parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser1.add_argument('-a')
args1 = parser1.parse_args()

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser2.add_argument('-b')
args2 = parser2.parse_args()
```

I have several questions:

1. Is parse_args a one-time method or is there a way to clear the
   arguments before adding new ones? (e.g. something like
   `args1.clear()` or `parser1.clear()`)
2. The result of this script is unusable. Although this script accepts
   the `-a` argument, it does not accept any value for 'a'. Nor does it
   accept any `-b` argument. Is there some way to make any of the arguments really work?
3. This is my actual scenario: I have 2 scripts. Both import the same
   file which has initialization code (load config files, create
   loggers, etc.), lets call it init.py This init.py file also parses
   the arguments only because it needs one value from it. The problem
   is that I need one of the scripts to accept other arguments as well.
   Since init.py does something with one argument, I cannot wait with
   parse_args. How can I make it work?

**Edit:**

Here is the output of my script:

[prompt]# python2.7 myscript.py -a

usage: a.py [-h] [-a A]

myscript.py: error: argument -a: expected one argument

[prompt]# python2.7 myscript.py -a 1

Namespace(a='1')

usage: a.py [-h] [-b B]

myscript.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -a 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario is quite unclear, but I guess what you're looking for is [`parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing)

Here I guessed that you called `init.py` from the other files, say `caller1.py` and `caller2.py`

Also suppose that `init.py` only parses `-a` argument, while the original script will parse the rest.

You can do something like this:

in `init.py` put this in `do_things` method:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a')
parsed = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv)
print 'From init.py: %s' % parsed['a']
```

In `caller1.py`:

```
init.do_things(sys.argv)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-b')
parsed = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv)
print 'From caller1.py: %s' % parsed['b']
```

If you call `caller1.py` as follows: `python caller1.py -a foo -b bar`, the result will be:

```
From init.py: foo
From caller1.py: bar
```

But if your scenario is not actually like this, I would suggest to use @Michael0x2a answer, which is just to use single `ArgumentParser` object in `caller1.py` and pass the value appropriately for `init.py`

Answer (score 2):

1. This doesn't really make sense, because for all intents and purposes, the parser object is stateless. There's nothing to clear, since all it does is takes in the console arguments, and returns a `Namespace` object (a pseudo-dict) without ever modifying anything in the process.

   Therefore, you can consider `parse_args()` to be idempotent. You can repeatedly call it over and over, and the same output will occur. By default, it will read the arguments from `sys.argv`, which is where the console arguments are stored.

   However, note that you can pipe in custom arguments by passing in a list to the `parse_args` function so that the parser will using something other then `sys.argv` as input.
2. I'm not sure what you mean. If you call `python myscript.py -a 15`, `args1` will equal `Namespace(a='15')`. You can then do `args1['a']` to obtain the value of 15. If you want to make the flag act as a toggle, call `parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')`. Here is [a list](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) of all available actions.
3. I would try and confine all the console/interface code into a single module and into a single parser. Basically, remove the code to parse the command line from init.py and the second file into an independent little section. Once you run the parser, which presents a unified interface for everything in your program, pass in the appropriate variables to functions inside `init.py`. This has the added advantage of keeping the UI separate and more easily interchangeable with the rest of the code.